How do I perform a function A set number of times and countdown each time it is performed?
I've created a time calculator to tell a user their time spent in flight.
I've figured out how to create these functions and call them however I'm not sure how to repeat a function again. In this case if the user specifies multiple flights were performed I'd need to repeatedly ask the user for the information for each flight. I think this  should be performed by a function that executes a number of times specified by the user or some kind of loop that adds a previous total to a new total.
But how do I write this code?
Do I have to assign a new value for every instance the user enters a new time?
How do I store previous times to add to a new time?
Here is the code:
#Function that calculates time accumulated.
def time_calc(take,land) :
    #Take off and landing time is split into two pieces.
    Tk =take[:2]
    Tk2 = take[2:]
    Ld = land[:2]
    Ld2 = land[2:]

    #The pieces of take off and landing time is converted into integers to perform math.
    int(Tk)
    int(Tk2)
    int(Ld)
    int(Ld2)

    #Conditions are created in order to calculate remaining time
    if Ld2 < Tk2:
        Lda = int(Ld) - 1
        Ld2 = 60

        Flight_time1 = int(Lda) - int(Tk)
        Flight_time2 = int(Ld2) - int(Tk2)

        #Final value is returned
        x = Flight_time1, "Hours", Flight_time2, "Minutes"
        return x

    else:
        Flight_time1 = int(Ld) - int(Tk)
        Flight_time2 = int(Ld2) - int(Tk2)

        #Final value is returned
        x = Flight_time1, "Hours", Flight_time2, "Minutes"
        return x

#Initial function to receive input from the user and call on the calculator function to perform math

def flight_form():
    Take_off1 = input ("Please enter take off time:")
    Landing1 = input ("Please enter Landing time:")
    Mult = input ("Was there multiple flights?(True or False)")

    take = Take_off1
    land = Landing1
    bool(Mult)

    if Mult == True:
        flight_number = input ("How many?")
        int(flight_number)

        x = time_calc(take,land)
        print (x)
    else:
        x = time_calc(take,land)
        print (x)

flight_form()

I was thinking of using a for loop. E.g, for flight_number() something perform this function x amount of times.
I'm unsure how to write this in code.

Of course use a loop. for i in range(flight_number):

int(flight_number) needs to be flight_number = int(flight_number). int() doesn't operate in place, it returns the number.

if Mult == True will never be true. Mult is a string.

And bool() doesn't parse strings. bool('False') returns True because any non-empty string is truthy.

You apparently have some problems with the basics of the language, you need to go back to the books.

What's the point of land = Landing1? If you want the variable to be named land in the rest of the code, use that when you call input().

The editor deleted the comment i made about my expierence level. I am a novice trying to learn the language. Theory is easy to read however applying it can be more difficult.     "For i in range" does i stand for something or is i just the syntax for this loop. Also are you saying i should specify which words would indicate true or false?

@NovicePytech Instead of trying to answer all of your questions in the comments here, I would recommend you follow any of the many free Python tutorials available online, such as Python.org or W3Schools.org.

A will give a  quick answer to your question about for loops:  for x in range(N): is the most common for loop.   range(N) tells it to iterate over the integers from 0 to N-1, and on each iteration, x will be set to that value at the start of the loop.   So the code for x in range(5): print(x)  will print the integers 0, 1, 2, 3, 4.  x can be any variable name.      The generalized for loop syntax is for <element> in <sequence>: where sequence is an iterable

you can add the loop in your if-clause if Mult == True. There you can try to make a list of the return values of time_calc or just add them in the for loop to your x.
def flight_form():
    Take_off1 = input ("Please enter take off time:")
    Landing1 = input ("Please enter Landing time:")
    Mult = input ("Was there multiple flights?(True or False)")

    take = Take_off1
    land = Landing1
    bool(Mult)

    if Mult == True:
        flight_number = input ("How many?")
        # here for loop option 1:
        x = 0
        for i in range(int(flight_number):
            take = input ("Please enter take off time:")
            land = input ("Please enter Landing time:")
            x = x + time_calc(take,land)
            print (x)
        # end of for loop

        # here for loop option 2:
        list_of_x = []
        for i in range(int(flight_number)):
            take = input ("Please enter take off time:")
            land = input ("Please enter Landing time:")
            x = time_calc(take,land)
            list_of_x.append(x)
            print (x)
        print("sum of time: " + sum(list_of_x))
        # end of for loop
    else:
        x = time_calc(take,land)
        print (x)


Thank you so much. I didn't properly understand how to create this for loop. However your two options have helped me understand how to apply it correctly.

for i in flight_number won't work. flight_number is a string, this loops over its characters, not a range of numbers. You're also missing the : at the end of the for line.

I would  first ask how many flights are involved, and then use a for loop to call the function flight_form()
def flight_form():
    Take_off = input("Please enter take off time:")
    Landing = input("Please enter Landing time:")
    x = time_calc(Take_off, Landing)
    print(x)

number_of_flights = input("How many times did you fly?")
number_of_flights = int(number_of_flights)

for i in range(number_of_flights):
    flight_form()


Thanks for your contribution. I'll take your advice and ask the number of flights first when I rewrite parts of the code.
